# Trying to add points to user, but not working

Tags: php

so I am trying to figure out a way to add a point to a user everytime they click a button, but I have not been able to figure it out. Right now, the button is showing and when the user clicks on it, nothing happens. Thanks for the help :)

```
 <table align="center">
    <caption><b>Users</b></caption>
    <br>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <th><img src="1.png" align="left"></th>


        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>     
    <?php 
    $user = new User();
    $get_all = DB::getInstance()->query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY points DESC Limit 0 , 20");
        foreach($get_all->results() as $r) {
    ?>
        <tr> 
            <td><?php echo ucfirst($r->username); ?>
            <?php echo ucfirst($r->points); if($r->points==140) {
                echo $r->username;
                }?> 
            <?php ucfirst($r->rank); if($r->points==140) {
                echo $r->rank; } ?>


<?php
$user = new User();


if(Input::exists()) {
    if(Token::check(Input::get('token'))) {
        $newPoints = Input::get('points') + 1; 

        try {
            $user->update(array(
                'points' => $newPoints
            ));
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }

        Session::flash('home', 'Your details have been updated.');
        Redirect::to('index.php');
    }
}
?>
<form method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="points_add" value="Points +1">
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>">
</form></td>

        </tr>
    <?php   }
    ?>  
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Your script looks for `Input::get('points')`, but your HTML has `name="points_add"`.

Comment: It also exepcted `points` to be a number, but you have `value="Points +1"`, which is a string.

Comment: @Barmar I am trying to say, take the current amount of points and add 1

Comment: Shouldn't you get the current amount from the database, not from `Input::get`?

Comment: @Barmar yea that is what I am trying to do but I am not sure how to do it

Comment: Put the userid in the hidden field, and do something like `UPDATE users SET points = points + 1 WHERE userid = $userid`, where `$userid` comes from the input.

Comment: @barmar so would I replace the  try {
            $user->update(array(
                'points' => $newPoints
            ));

Comment: You need a major rewrite.

Comment: @Barmar I still am pretty lost and idk if you are will to give an example of what it could look like, but if you are, I would really appreciate it

Comment: I'll try, but I can't figure out what your `User` class is doing in this. Does `User::update` write to the database? Where do you specify which user ID to update?

Comment: @Barmar it should be, because it has to find the current rank and then add 1 too it

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approximate answer. I had to make an assumption about your table schema (I guessed there's a `userid` column) and also about the database API (I wrote a parametrized query with the values as arguments to the `query` method -- you'll probably need to recode that to the proper method for your API, which I don't recognize).

```
<table align="center">
     <caption><b>Users</b></caption>
     <br>
     <thead>
     <tr>
     <th>Username</th>
     <th></th>
     <th></th>
     <th></th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <th><img src="1.png" align="left"></th>


     </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>     
     <?php 
     $get_all = DB::getInstance()->query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY points DESC Limit 0 , 20");
     foreach($get_all->results() as $r) {
    ?>
    <tr> 
    <td><?php echo ucfirst($r->username); ?>
    <?php echo ucfirst($r->points); if($r->points==140) {
         echo $r->username;
    } ?> 
    <?php if($r->points==140) {
         echo ucfirst($r->rank);
     } ?>


    <?php
    $user = new User();


    if(Input::exists()) {
        if(Token::check(Input::get('userid'))) {
            $userid = Input::get('userid');

            DB::getInstance()->query("UPDATE users SET points = points + 1 WHERE userid = ?", $userid);

            Session::flash('home', 'Your details have been updated.');
            Redirect::to('index.php');
        }
    }
    ?>
    <form method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="points" value="submit">
    <input type="hidden" name="userid" value="<?php echo $r->userid; ?>">
    </form></td>

    </tr>
    <?php   }
?>  
        </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: So I get this error when I click on the submit button "Not Acceptable

An appropriate representation of the requested resource / could not be found on this server."

Comment: Did you fix the assumptions I made so they correctly match your database and API?

Comment: also, I don't know if this helps but I made a function that adds 20 points when the user logs in and it looks like this "UPDATE `users` SET points = points + 20 WHERE `username` = '$user_username'";